# Check box in ListView layout has very short-term memory about being clicked

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-contacts

The code below to display Contact names works somewhat well:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class Authorize_Activity extends ListActivity {

    Cursor mContacts;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Return all contacts, ordered by name
        String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME }; // Would like the phone num, too
        mContacts = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                projection, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

        // Display all contacts in a ListView
        SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, mContacts,
                new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

}
```

..but the check boxes displayed with the names (via the native simple_list_item_multiple_choice layout) won't retain a click - the checkbox remains checked while you're pressing on it, but does not seem to remain clicked (either that, or the checkbox is black against a black background, like spots on a black panther, and I can't see it).

I see other people have had this issue in the past, too, but there HAS to be a less hacky/kludgy way of getting this to work than the complex workarounds that were mentioned. After all, what's the use of a check box if you can't check it?

Answer (score 1):

For Better performance and handling you should use BaseAdapter class and Normal Listview.I think using ListActivity is not a good idea when you want to customize your action or design.This has limited power in terms of both action and design

**Edited**

[See this link for adapter listview idea](http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1343)

Comment: see above link for more details about it